# Unable to obtain an authenticated token for running job __default with plan type Build and identifier Project Collection Build Service

Tags: tfs, build, build-agent

I am getting the below error when build is triggered, any hints on this?

> Unable to obtain an authenticated token for running job __default with plan type Build and identifier Project Collection Build Service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is sorted, just leaving this post here if anyone else come here looking for the same issue.

The problem was with the TFS server having no space. Got resolved when we free up some space.